# Can't Pass Parameters to jQuery Function Based on Hidden Page Content

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot to draw four charts which I want to display one at a time on a page i.e. switchable between them using button to select.  I have queried all the data for all of the graphs on page load. I want to store the data to generate the 3 alternate graphs in hidden divs and then swap them out as required.

So for example I have a button with id='weight_chart' that I want to use to switch the content in my chart div with id='chartdiv'. So I have the following function in my .js:

```
    $('#weight_chart').click(function(event) {

       $('#chartdiv').html(""); // clears the div         
       graph_data = $('#weight-graph-data').html();
       $.jqplot('chartdiv', graph_data);

    });
```

The parameters are all stored as html in a hidden div id='weight-graph-data'.

Now I kind of understand why it doesn't work. Trying to substitute my parameters like that using a string variable is the problem. If I just substitute the actual parameters in hard code ...

```
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],{ title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}});
```

in place of ...

```
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', graph_data);
```

... then it works fine.

So how do I pass parameters that I have calculated on page load later on when triggered by an event. I don't want to have to make another database call at this stage. I just want to take the portion of the parameters that I've already gathered ...

i.e.

```
[[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],{ title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}}
```

... and then pass that into the function.

I am a newbie at client side, so pls be patient. Thanks in advance for your help.

..................
UPDATE

Following the initial feedback I tried playing around with JSON and putting the parameters in javascript variables, but because the variables as a whole include the delimiters etc it doesn't seem to work.

So I tried a totally different approach with the intention of dynamically requerying the DB via ajax. I now correctly generate the pairs of values (the 2nd jqPlot parameter) and am simply trying to insert that piece while hard coding the rest. But it still won't work. Please see code below. I have tested for the value of 'results_list', and it is good. If I simply substitute the value in the place in the function call then it works fine and generates the graph, but coded as shown the graph is blank. Surely there must be a way to handle this sort of thing. Thanks again.

```
    $('.btn-graph').click(function(event) {

                var member_id = $('#member_id').val(); 
                var dataString = 'graph_type=' + this.id + '&member_id=' + member_id;
                //alert(dataString);

                    //alert (dataString);return false;  
                    $.ajax({  
                      type: "POST",  
                      url: "/ajax_handler/graph_data.php",  
                      data: dataString,
                      dataType: 'json',
                      success: function(data) {
                        //alert(data);
                        var results_list = "";
                        $.each(data, function(i,result){

                            results_list = results_list + "['" + result.date + "'," + result.bmi + "],"; 

                        });
                        results_list = results_list.slice(0, -1)
                        $('#chartdiv').html("");

                        $.jqplot('chartdiv',[[ results_list ]],{ title:'My Weight',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}});

                      }  
                    }); 
          });
```

.................... UPDATE 2

Thanks beetroot-beetroot - I got it just before I saw your update. I think your way would work also, but here's my solution that's working now:

As per dee38 here - [JSON for jqPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693579/json-for-jqplot) - Had to create name/value pairs in php. Then combine as small arrays into one big array. json_encode that and return via ajax. Then used eval(data) in ajax success function, and it all works. Here is the final jquery function:

```
    $('.btn-graph').click(function(event) {

            var member_id = $('#member_id').val(); 
            var dataString = 'graph_type=' + this.id + '&member_id=' + member_id;
            //alert(dataString);

                //alert (dataString);return false;  
                $.ajax({  
                  type: "POST",  
                  url: "/ajax_handler/graph_data.php",  
                  data: dataString,
                  success: function(data) {

                    $('#chartdiv').html("");

                    $.jqplot('chartdiv',eval(data),{ title:'BMI',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}});

                  }  
                }); 
  });
```

And my php at the backend is ...

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stats WHERE id = '".$mid."'");


//Create an array with the results
$pairs=array();
while($v = mysql_fetch_object($sql)){
    $pairs[$v->date] = (float) $v->bmi;
}

$result = array();

foreach ($pairs as $label => $value) {
    $result[] = array($label,$value); // make a "small" array for each pair
}

echo json_encode(array($result));
```

Comment: in response to your Update, see my edit.

Comment: On your UPDATE 2: [don't use `eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21), use `$.parseJSON` instead. Better yet, pass `dataType : 'json'` to `$.ajax`, and let jQuery do that for you automatically.

Comment: I had originally tried passing dataType json, but jqPlot could not seem to handle the data no matter what I did with it from there. Now I pass the data as described in my solution and just use eval(data) and it works perfectly. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use jQuery's parseJSON function if your JSON string is just represented in your element's HTML:

```
graph_data = $.parseJSON($('#weight-graph-data').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Will Domaine's suggestion sounds good but an alternative is to store the three sets of graph data as javascript vars rather than as strings in the DOM.

For example,

```
var graphData = [
    [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],{ title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}},
    [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],{ title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}},
    [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],{ title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}},
];
```

(I have used the same data x3 but your three will be different).

Then build your buttons as follows :

```
<button class="weightChart" data-index="0">Weight Chart 1</button>
<button class="weightChart" data-index="1">Weight Chart 2</button>
<button class="weightChart" data-index="2">Weight Chart 3</button>
```

Then animate the buttons with :

```
$('.weightChart').click(function(event) {
    $('#chartdiv').empty();
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', graphData[Number($(this).attr('data-index'))]);
});
```

Edit ....

Looking at the data in more detail, I see that each dataset consists of two vars, not one. This is probably what's screwing you up whatever you try.

My js approach revised:

```
var graphData = [
    {
        coords: [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],
        options: { title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}}
    },
    {
        coords: [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],
        options: { title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}}
    },
    {
        coords: [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],
        options: { title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}}
    }
];
```

(Again, same data x3)

Now animate the buttons with :

```
$('.weightChart').click(function(event) {
    $('#chartdiv').empty();
    var data = graphData[Number($(this).attr('data-index'))];
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', data.coords, data.options);
});
```

If the options are always the same, then this would simplify as follows.

```
var graphOptions = { title:'Body Mass Index',axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}}};
var graphData = [
    [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],
    [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]],
    [[['2012-03-30',30.80],['2012-03-31',30.59]]]
];
```

with :

```
$('.weightChart').click(function(event) {
    $('#chartdiv').empty();
    var data = graphData[Number($(this).attr('data-index'))];
    $.jqplot('chartdiv', data, graphOptions);
});
```