# jqPlot Chart – Doesn’t display the ajax data

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jqplot

I’m using the jqPlot “AJAX JSON Data Renderer” as described in: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php. 
My server side is Spring MVC. On the server I render a matrix of Object[][], each line of the matrix contains 2 objects: [LocalTime.toString(“HH:mm”), Integer]. Response is returned as “@ResponseBody”

I can see that the data is retrieved from the server and when I display it in an alert I see the following:

`[["09:00",5],["09:30",5],["10:00",5],["10:30",5],["11:00",10],["11:30",10],["12:00",10],["12:30",10],["13:00",5]]`

I also tried using `List<List<Object>>` instead of the array.
I cant get it to work. All I get is an empty chart.
Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
        var ret = null;
        $.ajax({
          async: false,
          url: url,
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(data) {
            ret = data;
          }
        });
        alert("OUT: " + ret);
        return ret;
      };
       var jsonurl = "chartData";

      var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart', jsonurl,{
        dataRenderer: ajaxDataRenderer,
        dataRendererOptions: {
          unusedOptionalUrl: jsonurl
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

I saw in here [JSON for jqPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693579/json-for-jqplot) that everyone suggests to build a string and parse it. Is this the only way?
I also reviewed several similar questions but couldn’t find me an answer.
Will appreciate any hint…

Comment: according to the data renderer documentation, jsonurl should have the ajax url, and not "chartData"... where did that come from?

Comment: Most likely as @Rodik says your `url` is not valid. What chartData really means in the context of you web app is it your servlet's name? Try running your app in `FireFox` and see how does that `url looks like in `Firebug` then see if it matches your servlet's `url`.

Comment: chartData is the http url which is mapped in my Controller to the method that returns the Object[][] matrix. What does "ajax url" mean? I don't think that this is the problem since I receive the response.

Comment: Meron You are right if you are getting the response and it is formatted well then the `url` is fine. I am sure that by ajax `url` @Rodik means the `url` you give to your `ajax` request. Please also check out my answer I think this must be the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked ages ago, so I assume you have moved on by now...but I was searching for this as well...and have just found the answer.  Well...AN answer.

The issue is that the thing you are passing back from ajaxDataRenderer stops looking like json when you put the dates in.  I dont know why, but if you change dataType to text, then your alert will output the data.  But the chart fails, because it isn't set up to handle a string.

so....you use eval, to force js to convert the string into an actual array, like this:

```
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
     var ret = null;

     $.ajax({
      // have to use synchronous here, else the function
      // will return before the data is fetched
      async: false,
      url: url,
      dataType:"text",
      success: function(data) {
          ret = data;
          }
    });

    //clear out the loading message from the div
    $('#chartdiv').empty();
    //evaluate the returned string...to turn it into the data structure.
    return eval(ret);
};
```

This worked for me anyway.  I then made my url to return text representing the data.

Hope this helps someone else searching for the answer to this!

Answer (score 0):

[This sample jsfiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/X9jEz/) how in your case the data that goes into the plot should look like.

Since you are using time (date) on your x axis you must tell the chart how to render it and there is no better way to do it then by using `DateAxisRenderer`. The code below (also in the sample) shows how it is done:

```
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            label: "x label",
            renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
            tickOptions:{formatString:'%H:%M'}
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, I added the `DateAxisRenderer` still no good. I can see that the canvas is displayed (added min and max to the xaxis) with the min and max values but no graph. Do you have another idea? Maybe its a synchronization problem? Should the sript be located in the html header?

Comment: In my opinion put your script always in the header. Though it might be something else. I have already showed in the jsfiddle in my answer how to format your data other then that I simply cannot guess what might be wrong in your code. Why don't you build a http://jsfiddle.net that shows your problem?

Comment: @Boro you should always put scripts at the foot of the page - this is because the browser has to stop all rendering/layout to download JS files in place just in case they contain a document.write().  This is a best practise advised in YSlow and PageSpeed

Comment: @earcam Thanks for the info. All my life I been thought to put all into a header thus my opinion :) I am very much interested by what you are saying. Would you mind expanding your comment with some links to resources where I could read more about this approach cause this is the first time I hear about it? And yes I googled for the YSlow and PageSpeed and I am reading about them right now trying to find the interesting part.

Comment: I think I got it now. To those interested a great example is here http://stevesouders.com/examples/move-scripts.php

Comment: Hi @Boro, I was just about to reply with an example; put a script in <head> that does document.write('<title>hello</title>'), demonstrating scripts are evaluated inline (however doesn't show halt in rendering).  +1 for the link, that Steve Souders chap wrote YSlow and has a couple of books on webpage performance - genuinely good stuff.  cheers.